# Transfermarkt webscrapping failed

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, jupyter

I have created the code below to scrape data from Transfermarkt but it gives error

ERROR

---

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11132/2460347319.py in 
2
3 #Let's look at the first name in the Players list.
----> 4 Players[0].text

IndexError: list index out of range

---

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

page = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/transfers/transferrekorde/statistik/top/plus/0/galerie/0?saison_id=2000"
pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')

Players = pageSoup.find_all("a", {"class": "spielprofil_tooltip"})

#Let's look at the first name in the Players list.
Players[0].text
```

Thanks

Comment: There seems to be no class `spielprofil_tooltip` in your html, so `Players` is empty. That's why you can't do Players[0]. It's an empty list.

Comment: `Players = pageSoup.find_all("table", {'class': 'items'})`

Answer (score 0):

Your link has no tags 'a' with the specified class "spielprofil_tooltip".

[image]

So the python list is empty and the zero index has None in the value place.

```
Players = pageSoup.find_all("a", {"class": "spielprofil_tooltip"})
Players[0].text # convert a value that not exist raise a exception
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still looking for scrapping player data from Transfermarkt, you can have a look at [this class](https://github.com/dcaribou/transfermarkt-scraper/blob/ba1f2e61ae26dd9e492433b51d955b7774919d4d/tfmkt/spiders/players.py#L7).

There are a few other datasets that the project is scraping that you may also be interested in, I'd suggest to have a look [here](https://github.com/dcaribou/transfermarkt-scraper).

Disclaimer: I wrote that scraper.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31660922)